# How to handle all UI changes in a different class?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android application that has a lot of UI changes. I know in order to alter a view, I must do the following:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        //alter views
    }
});
```

I have found that I have used this method several times throughout my code and it seems cluttered. How might I create a class that will handle all UI changes for an activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am supposing that you are doing this from inside a different thread (Of course. Why else you would need to call `runOnUiThread` specifically?) My 2 cent is that have you considered using `AsyncTask` for handing UI change after/before your background operation starts? This will clear things a bit for you and that's a better/proper way of handling your interacition between UI/Non-UI thread.

Comment: @user3708826 Its okay. I hope it helped. You can still mark the answer accepted if it helped solve the issue.